How to ignore linter rules in generated files with specific extensions like `.g.dart or .gr.dart` in Flutter
I'm using the slang package in my Flutter project to generate translation files. These generated files have extensions like .g.dart or .gr.dart. However, the linter flags various issues in these files, which I would like to ignore. The other reason is, the generated files have almost 1,000 lines of code, So it would be quite hard to fix all the issues. Knowling that the next code generation will still bring them back.
Is there a way to configure the Dart linter to ignore specific rules or all rules in files with certain extensions? Ideally, I'd like a solution that can be applied project-wide, so I don't have to manually edit each generated file ?
I want to disable these linter rules for all .g.dart and .gr.dart files. Any help would be appreciated!

Just add exclude rules in analysis_options.yaml in analyzer section, for example:
analyzer:
  exclude: 
    - '**/*.g.dart'

linter:
 ... rules ...

More information here
